# Is there a concise way to unwrap and assign in swift?

Tags: memory, swift

I have an ugly (but working) chunk of unwrapping code in swift:

```
var color = UIColor.whiteColor()
if ( label.backgroundColor? != nil )
{
  color = label.backgroundColor!
}
```

*Is there any more concise way to write this in swift like I would do in C++?*

```
UIColor color = (label.backgroundColor==nil) ?
  UIColor.whiteColor() : label.backgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Swift has the "nil coalescing operator" `??` which does exactly what you
are looking for:

```
let color = label.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.whiteColor()
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124), `a ?? b` is a shortcut for

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

where `b` is only evaluated if `a == nil` (short-circuit evaluation).

Comment: Awesome! I missed that reading through the documentation. Very handy to know.

Comment: @0O0O0O0: `??` was introduced only in Xcode 6 beta 5, so it was easy to miss that.